# How do I access my strongly typed config model while configuring services from an extension method?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, .net-5

Given:

```cs
public class MyConfigModel
{
    public string ConfigValueOne { get; set; }
}


public static class MyIServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterMyService(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<MyConfigModel> optionsOverrides
    )
    {
        services
            .AddOptions<MyConfigModel>()
            .Configure(optionsOverrides);

        MyConfigModel myConfig = /* ??? */;

        services.AddOtherService((otherServiceOptions)
        {
            otherServiceOptions.SomethingElse = myConfig.ConfigValueOne;
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

How do I obtain a value for `myConfig` above, or what alternate technique must I use to accomplish some equivalent to `RegisterMyService`?

I'd like to avoid requiring callers to pass in an `IConfiguration` instances if at all possible. This is because they're already providing an `Action<MyConfigModel>`.

The goal here is that I want to be able to leverage my own configuration (`MyConfigModel`) from within my extension method. But I'd also like to offer the option for overrides from the options system as well as in code, hence the `Action<MyConfigModel>` on `RegisterMyService`.

Comment: resolve the IOptions<MyConfigModel> in the factory delegate when registering your other services

Comment: Sorry, which factory delegate is that?  Maybe an example?

Comment: We can build provider from `IServiceCollection` and resolve instance of `IOptions<MyConfigModel>` or `IConfiguration`.

Comment: You can only build the provider if you have a ServiceCollection, not IServiceCollection.

Comment: Did you solve it?